# ORACLE SQL: How can I get the XML elements from within a column of XMLTYPE

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have an multiple xml documents which look like this:

```
<farm>
    <name>Johns Farm</name>
    <size>50 hectares</size>
    <employees>20</employees>
    <fruits>
        <fruit>Banana</fruit>
        <fruit>Apple</fruit>
        <fruit>Watermelon</fruit>
    </fruits>
</farm>
```

I have got this in an oracle database like this:

```
CREATE TABLE FARM_XML_TABLE
(FARM_NUMBER NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, FARM_XML XMLTYPE NOT NULL)
XMLTYPE COLUMN FARM_XML STORE AS BINARY XML
XMLSCHEMA
  "http://myproject.com/farmschema.xsd"
  ELEMENT "farm";
```

The various farms are stored in the `FARM_XML` column. There is about 5 of them

How can I retrieve only the name and employee elements from the `FARM_XML` column of multiple farms in the form of an XML. I want the output to be like this:

```
<farm>
<name>Johns Farm</name>
<employees>20</employees>
</farm>

<farm>
<name>Harrys Farm</name>
<employees>10</employees>
</farm>
```

I have tried doing this, but the output isn't all the xml elements that I want.

```
SELECT extract(FARM_XML, 'farm/name').getStringVal()
FROM FARM_XML_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE FARM_XML_TABLE(
  FARM_NUMBER NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  FARM_XML XMLTYPE NOT NULL
)
XMLTYPE COLUMN FARM_XML STORE AS BINARY XML;

INSERT INTO FARM_XML_TABLE VALUES(
  1,
  XMLtype( '<farm>
    <name>Johns Farm</name>
    <size>50 hectares</size>
    <employees>20</employees>
    <fruits>
        <fruit>Banana</fruit>
        <fruit>Apple</fruit>
        <fruit>Watermelon</fruit>
    </fruits>
</farm>' )
);
```

**Query 1 - Rebuild the XML**:

```
SELECT FARM_NUMBER,
       XMLElement(
         "farm",
         XMLElement( "name",      EXTRACTVALUE( farm_xml, '/farm/name' ) ),
         XMLElement( "employees", EXTRACTVALUE( farm_xml, '/farm/employees' ) )
       ) AS xml
FROM   FARM_XML_TABLE;
```

or (updated - simpler version):

```
SELECT FARM_NUMBER,
       XMLElement(
         "farm",
         EXTRACT( farm_xml, '/farm/name' ),
         EXTRACT( farm_xml, '/farm/employees' )
       ) AS xml
FROM   FARM_XML_TABLE;
```

**Query 2 - Delete non-matching elements from the existing XML**:

```
SELECT FARM_NUMBER,
       DELETEXML(
         farm_xml,
         '/farm/*[name()!=''name''][name()!=''employees'']'
       ) AS xml
FROM   FARM_XML_TABLE;
```

**Output**:

*(Both output the same)*

```
FARM_NUMBER XML
----------- -------------------------------------------------------------
          1 <farm><name>Johns Farm</name><employees>20</employees></farm>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the detailed reply.

Comment: @Hokkaido Updated with a simpler version of Query 1.